# Extracting part of a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract, submatrix

I have a matrix say `(+)`   order, I want to extract first    order matrix, like say

[image: `A matrix],

I want to extract first

[image: required]

Comment: You may need to read something about [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by rahnema1, you can use [Matrix Indexing](https://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) in matlab as follows:

```
partA = A(1:p, :)
```

or for your specific example:

```
partA = A(1:3, :)
```

**Explanation**

- `1:p`: selects all rows between `1` and `p`.
- `:` selects all columns.

**Further reading**

As this seems a basic question to me, it may be useful to have a look at the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial.